# Is there an ASP.NET equivalent of SwiftMailer for PHP?

Tags: asp.net, email, smtp

We are looking at sending some email notifications to about 1100 employees at a time. Each email would contain some personalized information, so sending one email with a huge BCC is out. Looping through and sending one at a time seems dumb.

In some of my homebrew projects I solved this type of problem by using [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) to send bulk email from PHP. Is there any equivalent, preferably free, for ASP.NET?

**Update:**

It seems like there is no direct equivalent to SwiftMailer (at least one that's free) so I've gone ahead and marked the answer that we didn't use another library. We haven't had any problems sending email though, and our code has been in production for quite a while now.

There are also new templating options that look interesting: http://razorengine.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can simply use `SmtpClient` class which is already bundled with .Net framework? 
See

- http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/email/email-aspnet2-vb.aspx for simple tutorial
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx - msdn documentation and examples

Comment: i've sent a couple thousand different messages in a simple loop with SmtpClient and it only took about 45 seconds (to an SMTP server on the same machine, admittedly).   It also has SendAsync if you want to do them async

Comment: This is what I've used before (at least I think so), it just seemed like there might be a better way ala SwiftMailer.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the examples that come with the mailer libraries from http://www.advancedintellect.com/.  It works with background threads and datasets. I did some php work with SwiftMailer previously.  The AI products is what I have decided upon for my .Net development work.

Comment: This looks interesting but I don't know if we're willing to pay.

Comment: Normally I would agree with you.  In some cases though you have to estimate the time it would take to write the code yourself (or your team) at an hourly rate. Then compare to the price of a library such as this. 

I have to do this myself as I want to write everything myself.

Comment: That's true. I'm perfectly willing to use a good third party library. I may be able to convince the boss another time, but it doesn't seem too likely for this application. All the local governments around here have been hit pretty hard in the budget area.